# Hive and sql( any sql query)

Tags: sql, hive

I am posting question here related to hive dataware house?I have below sample data

```
    Id,name,transctions
1,apple,(1,1,1,1)
2,mango,(1,1,1)
3,kiwi,(1,1,1)
...........
.......
```

In transctions column  my data is array type. I am expecting below output.

```
Id,name,transtion  
1,apple,4
2,mango,3
3,kiwi,3
```

Comment: Where does the "5" come from on the first row?

Comment: Sorry typo mistake, its not 5 its 4

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the size of the array:

```
select id, name, [size(transactions)][1]
from t;
```

Comment: Could you give some idea about what is size(..)?

Comment: Hi Gordon, Is that hive query or Any sql?

Comment: @Imran . . . That is Hive documentation, just as your question is tagged.